# Asp Net MVC longPolling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, longpolling, requisição

Tenho um projeto asp net mvc 5, verifiquei que a cada segundo é feita uma requisição, passando esses parametros = `transport=longPolling&connectionToken=""`, e como resposta vem `{"C":"d-5B01A8B9-CN,0|Dw,B|Dx,0","M":[]}`, que seria isso?

Comment: Possivelmente é uma conexão socket feita por JavaScript. Sua aplicação tem SignalR instalado?

Comment: Não tem, e percebi também que só aparece essas requisições quando estou em ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dando uma pesquisada na net, verifiquei que esse comportamento ocorre, porque está utilizando o Browser Link do Visual Studio 2013.

O Browser Link é um recurso do Visual Studio 2013, que cria um canal de comunicação entre o ambiente de desenvolvimento e um ou mais navegadores web. Você pode usar o navegador o link para atualizar seu aplicativo da web em vários navegadores ao mesmo tempo, o que é útil para testes de cross-browser.

Para desativar, é só remover essa opção:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917595/net-localhost-website-consistently-making-get-arterysignalr-polltransport-long
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link