# O que é Browser Link?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Quando utilizo o Visual Studio (estou utilizando a versão 2013, não sei se as anteriores possuem) com o [Browser Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013/) habilitado, sempre há uma requisição GET no console (F12) do browser. O que seria esta requisição?

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://domain.com/__browserLink/requestData/45d702dfc31b4ded88bc432b6dfdb762?version=2".
```

Abrindo o arquivo, vejo o seguinte código minificado: [Arquivo no Pastebin por ser muito extenso.](https://pastebin.com/kYBUgLFv)

[Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82342/20615) é informado que:

> O Browser Link é um recurso do Visual Studio 2013, que cria um canal de comunicação entre o ambiente de desenvolvimento e um ou mais navegadores web. Você pode usar o navegador o link para atualizar seu aplicativo da web em vários navegadores ao mesmo tempo, o que é útil para testes de cross-browser.

O autor diz que é um **Canal de Comunicação**, mas o que se comunica?

Qual a utilidade dessa conexão?

Isso deixa o ambiente de desenvolvimento mais lento?

**Nota:** Não estou utilizando o SignalR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando Browser Link está habilitado o Visual Studio funciona como um servidor SignalR onde browsers se conectam via um script injetado na página html renderizada.

Basicamente serve para atualizar páginas de vários browsers, simultaneamente, quando você as abre na IDE:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém a melhor definição (e dica) é a seguinte:

> Na mais recente edição da saga épica da Microsoft, *'Coisas que ninguém pediu'*, nos foi dado o *Browser Link*. Sem dúvida alguma a coisa mais importante que você precisa saber sobre ele é como desligá-lo. Você pode fazê-lo de forma global, alterando a opção de dentro do Visual Studio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte aqui.](http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/)