# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest e XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Quando carrego a minha página aparece essas 2 mensagens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo a codificação da minha página.

```
@model SistemaComercial.Models.ItensVenda

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Adicionar novo item";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageCadastro.cshtml";
@* ----- Boostrap ----- *@
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
}
<h2 class="text-primary text-center">Novo Item</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border"></legend>
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <b>Código Venda</b>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CodigoVenda, new {@readonly = "readonly" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoVenda)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            <b>Código Produto</b>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CodigoProduto) <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Consulta", "Venda", new { CodigoVenda = @ViewBag.CodigoVenda })'">Consulta</button>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodigoProduto)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
           <b>Quantidade</b>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantidade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantidade)
        </div><br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            <b>Preco Unitário</b>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @ViewBag.ValorUnitario
        </div><br /><br />

        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Movimentacao", "Venda", new { Codigo = @ViewBag.CodigoVenda })'">Cancelar</button>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar (F5)" id="AjaxPost" />
        <br />
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>

 }
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

       $("#AjaxPost").click(function () {
        $("#content").html("<b>Aguarde...</b>");

        var dataObject = {
            CodigoVenda: $("#CodigoVenda").val(),
            CodigoProduto: $("#CodigoProduto").val(),
            Quantidade: $("#Quantidade").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SalvarItem","Venda")",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: dataObject,
            dataType: "json",
           });

       });
   });
```

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é Browser Link?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97367/o-que-%C3%A9-browser-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este erro não é do seu código, repare no nome do arquivo em que está dando o erro, este é um arquivo do Browser Link, um recurso do Visual Studio, repare inclusive que a porta usada por esse arquivo (59671) é diferente pela porta que você está usando no seu site (63729).

O Browser Link é um recurso do Visual Studio que permite por exemplo que você atualize todos os navegadores que estão com sua página aberta com o clique de um botão dentro do Visual Studio, ou que ele recarregue um arquivo css automaticamente quando você salva ele no Visual Studio sem precisar recarregar a página.

Então eu diria que você pode ignorar este erro que ele não deve causar problema algum e só vai aparecer enquanto estiver desenvolvendo, quando publicar o site para o servidor de produção ele não vai ocorrer.