# O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented - BrowserLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Eu recebo esse erro em todas as páginas, quando browserlink está ativada:

> O método getPreventDefault() não deve mais ser usado. No lugar, use defaultPrevented.  browserLink:37:40278

Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desmarcando `Browser Link`, o erro desaparece.

Alguma solução com `Browser Link` marcado?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é Browser Link?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97367/18246)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não. O browser link é um recurso do Visual Studio que funciona injetando código JavaScript nas páginas.

Se quer continuar usando o recurso, vai continuar recebendo a mensagem. Se isso for um *warning* é possível desativar dependendo do *browser*. Se for realmente um erro que está te impedindo de testar a aplicação, provavelmente atualizar o browser link para uma versão mais nova vai solucionar.